# How to dynamically import a javascript array from a URL?

Tags: javascript, url, import, module

I have this code:

```
import("./static.js") .them (m => {...})
```

where `m` is some static array defined in static.js
How to I accomplish this?

```
import("https://somesite.com/public/static.js")
.them (m => {...})
```

because this gets me a Module not found exception
There has got to be a simple answer without having to set up a server to serve up the file via REST.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer, which is to use fetch:

```
fetch(url).then (res => res.text())....
```

As for the inevitable CORS related issue fetching from a remote website, I added this to the NGINX server configuration on that website:

```
location / {
.......
add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"  *;
```